# Modules for Laying Out Content-submission Forms

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

In reviewing Drupal layout modules, I'm left with the impression that while many exist for formatting **existing** content (e.g. Panels, Views and Display Suite), there are very few (if any) that focus on changing the layout of **content-submission** forms - and therefore there's no alternative but modifying the associated templates themselves. Is this a correct impression? And if so, I'm curious as to why so little focus on content-submission modules. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Panels will let you change the node/add node/edit forms.

Comment: Kevin, thank you so much. I missed that capability completely.